# random duplicate images in a folder Python tkinter

Tags: python, datetime, filenames

im making an application that you can specify how many random images you want to generate.
The random image data is taken from this url https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080.
whenever i generate new images you can see in the folder that he created duplicate images.
this might not be a programming problem but im spending a lot of time figuring out how to fix it.
my goal is to find out why the link sometimes generates a duplicate image.
I would appreciate any help i can get.

for better understanding here is my code:

```
modules = ["pip", "requests", "datetime"]

try:
    import time
    from time import sleep
    import urllib
    from tkinter.ttk import *
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
    import os
    import requests
    import io
    from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
    from datetime import datetime
    import subprocess
    import threading
    from threading import Thread
except ImportError:
    import sys
    import pip
    import subprocess
    module_installation_question = input(
        "Some modules are missing, do you want to install all required modules for this project? yes or no.: ").lower()
    if module_installation_question == "yes":
        for module in modules:
            subprocess.call(['pip', 'install', module])
        print("Restart the editor and this project should work...")
        sys.exit()
    elif module_installation_question == "no":
        print("This project won't work if one module is missing...")
        sys.exit()

Image_creator = tk.Tk()
Image_creator.geometry("520x530")
Image_creator.configure(bg="#1A1A1A")

button = tk.Button(Image_creator, text="Start",
                   command=lambda: test())
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")

url = "https://source.unsplash.com/random/1920x1080"
image_connection1 = ""

reopen_programm_format = '"{}" "{}" "{}"'.format(
    sys.executable,
    __file__,
    os.path.basename(__file__),
    sys.exit,
)


def test():
    for i in range(20):
        extracting_images_from_web()
        sleep(2)
        storing_images()


def storing_images(directory="images downloaded"):
    time_now = datetime.now()
    time_now_format = time_now.strftime("%d.%m.%Y - %H.%M.%S")
    try:
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
        filename = f"{time_now_format}" + ".jpg"
        with open(os.path.join(directory, filename), "wb") as saving_image:
            saving_image.write(image_connection1)
            saving_image.close()
    except:
        showinfo("Error", "Random Error ocurred...")


def extracting_images_from_web():
    global image_connection1
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as connection1:
            image_connection1 = connection1.read()
    except urllib.error.URLError:
        showinfo("No Internet Connection",
                 "You need an active internet connection!")


Image_creator.mainloop()
```

Comment: what do you mean duplicated images? e.g `image1` `image1(1)` `image1(2)` ?

Comment: whenever an image is taken from this url and saved in the folder it will be named from this specific time, e.g 19.51.23. And when using loop for repeating this task,  then there are chances that generates 2 same images next together (most of the times) .that is my only problem.

Comment: you can add a  `time.sleep` to stop the code running several times, I don't see how the duplication would happen as you have `os.path.exists` above?

Comment: sorry for late reply, i found the problem when you keep refreshing the link on browser sometimes shows same image, seems like i can't fix this or can i?